# consumer account's for cloud identity via PI

Tags: user-management, google-cloud-identity

I am using the Cloud Identity basic and I am admin. 
my domain and it's subdomain have many consumer account, which we got to know via "Transfer tool for unmanaged users" . Now the question is :-

how to manage / add consumer accounts via API, as I am looking for the automated process 
but details available below link is hard stop for me.
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migrating-consumer-accounts-to-cloud-identity-or-g-suite
https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7044710?hl=en&ref_topic=7558419

it is going to create the account with overriding the existing managed id. which I do not want , I want to send email to user for account migration [which is possible via admin UI but seems not with API, but in my organization manual addition of many users is not ]

1) Is there a way by google API to identify adding user, is a consumer account for my domain and subdomain or not? some way or the another , so new user and consumer accounts can be managed separately. 
2) I do not want to "Require users to rename their existing account." as it will be more difficult for my org and unmanaged.

Any direction will be welcome , and let me know if more information needed.

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migrating-consumer-accounts-to-cloud-identity-or-g-suite
https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7044710?hl=en&ref_topic=7558419

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is currently no public API to initiate a user transfer or to query whether a given email address is used by a consumer user account. This functionality is currently only exposed via the UI in the *transfer tool for unmanaged users*.

However, if you have a large number of consumer accounts that you need to send transfer, then Support might be able to help you.